# How Do I Switch Axes on Embedded Chart using Google App Code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

How Do I Switch Axes on Embedded Chart using Google App Code.  Currently I have the Column data showing on the h axis with the row day=ta (dates) on the V.  I need them the other way around and can't find the method to switch them.  Does anyone know?   Sorry I'm a newbie!!

Answer (score 1):

As an example, I have a column chart with X axis A and Y axis B.  I switch it so X is B and Y is A.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Copy of Sheet3");
    let chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
    chart = chart.modify().asColumnChart().reverseCategories().build();
    sheet.updateChart(chart);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [EmbeddedColumnChart.reverseCategories()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-column-chart-builder#reverseCategories())

Comment: Thanks for this.  I tried the reverseCategories, but this just reversed the way that the data was presentented on the actual axis without reversing the axes themselves.  Is there any way I can spcify the series I want on each axis to prevent the system actually choosing it for me?

Comment: I guress I don't understand your question.